# Toggle network share on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, script, network-shares, cmd.exe

I need help with mounting a samba share with a shortcut/button. I want to be able to mount a share and unmount it with the same button. Here is the pseudo code i had in mind. Requirements are simple: if the share is not mounted then mount it, if the share is mounted unmount it - so sort of a "toggle" shortcut.

Two command i use are:

`net use W: \\192.168.1.5\marko somepassword /USER:marko /PERSISTENT:YES`

`net use /del W:`

Thanks!

EDIT: Also, is there a way to hide the plain text password?

Answer (score 1):

In your batch file:

```
IF EXIST W:\ GOTO UNMOUNT
  net use W: \\192.168.1.5\marko somepassword /USER:marko /PERSISTENT:YES
:UNMOUNT
  net use /delete W:
```

EDIT:
To create a shortcut on the Desktop.

Right-click -> New -> Text Document
Open the file with notepad or another text editor
Copy the code to the file
Rename the file to 'mountw.bat' or something similar with a .bat extension

Comment: That should generally work, except for `/del` should be replaced with the full form `/delete`

Comment: So how do i make it into a button/shortcut for the user to double click in the desktop?

Comment: Create a text file called toggle-mount-w-drive.bat. Open it with notepad. Paste above code into it, then save. Store the file somewhere safe and create a shortcut to it on the desktop. You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to it and change the icon via shortcut properties\

Comment: Thanks guys, is there a way to obfuscate the password?

Comment: No, but you can get away with using NTFS permissions to block access to file for anyone accept your own user. Just make sure you understand, this will not make it completely secure, just harder to access

Comment: I believe this needs amending. Firstly, this would fail because it should be `net use W: \\...` without the backslash after the colon. Secondly, this will just delete the map immediately after creating it, you need to exit before the goto label.

Comment: @mbiber [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22943847/5327283) will leverage PowerShell to prompt for a password, and user input will be masked.